# Using data from a joined query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I a controller I have a query with a join to prevent the 1+n problem:

```
@questions = Question.joins(:answers).where("answers.user_id = ?", user_id)
```

Now I want to iterate the questions in the view and use them:

```
- @questions.each do |question|
  - answer = question.answers.first
```

But the result is that the answers table is queried twice. How can I get to the answers from the first join query, so I don't need the second query?

Comment: Note: `Question.joins(:answers)` will return duplicate results, since you are inner joining a `has-many` relationship.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you really want to return only the answers given by the user, or do you want all the other users' answers too?

Assuming the former, another approach might be:

```
@questions = @user.answers.eager_load(:question).group_by{|answer| answer.question}
```

This would give you a single query that joins answers and questions, then the group_by will return a hash in which the keys are the questions and the values are arrays of the user's answers.

If you want all answers by all users then you'd want an association from User that gives you the questions that they've answered (a has_many :questions_answered, through: :answers, class_name: "question"), then:

```
@questions = @user.questions_answered.include(:answers)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@questions = Question.includes(:answers).where(answers: {user_id: user_id})
```

Joins just allows the query on the users table, it doesn't avoid n+1.  Using includes tells rails to eager load answers so will avoid it.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#eager-loading-associations

Comment: This returns an error: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "answers"

Comment: [RailsGuides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-eager-loaded-associations) says: > Using where like this will only work when you pass it a Hash. For SQL-fragments you need use references to force joined tables. So you have 2 options here: 1 - `Question.includes(:answers).where("answers.user_id = ?", user_id).references(:answers)`, 2 - `Question.includes(:answers).where(answers: {user_id: user_id})`.

Comment: Thanks @AndreyTurkin, updated answer to reflect that.